# How to display image to full screen through dynamically created imageview using Myadapter

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to display image to full screen using my function showImage(final Uri imageUri) when I click dynamically created imageview using Myadapter, someone plesae provide solution.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mnt);
    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
}
```

Function to display image in fullscreen

```
 public void showImage(final Uri imageUri) {
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(Mnt.this);
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //nothing;
        }
    });

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Mnt.this);
    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    builder.show();
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public final class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    mItems.add(new Item("1",       R.drawable.m1));
    mItems.add(new Item("2",   R.drawable.m2));
    mItems.add(new Item("3", R.drawable.m3));
    mItems.add(new Item("4",      R.drawable.m4));
    mItems.add(new Item("5",     R.drawable.m1));
    mItems.add(new Item("6",      R.drawable.m2));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i).drawableId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    ImageView picture;
    TextView name;

    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
    }

    picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
    name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

    Item item = getItem(i);

    picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
    name.setText(item.name);

    return v;
}

private static class Item {
    public final String name;
    public final int drawableId;

    Item(String name, int drawableId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}
```

**activity_mnt.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**SquareImageView.java**

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
}}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I'm not getting the idea to call my function showImage(uri)

Comment: Why dont you modify it for passing an int?

Comment: Pls explain in detail i.e. pls suggest all necessary changes in function showImage(Uri) to modify.

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT** instead of **ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT** 
or you haven't give layoutparams to imageview so that is why it is taking only the size of image in screen. 
Try this and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question is not about WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT. I want to know how to call my function showImage(final Uri imageUri)?

Comment: did you check the second line you forgot to give layout size to your imageview object

Answer (score 0):

Set LayoutParam for your image view.

```
LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

imageView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

The question is vague. But i think you mean this. Try it and tell me if something is up.

First, save the context

```
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    ...
}
```

Then setTag(drawableId) on your picture and put a click event.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
   View v = view;
   ImageView picture;
   TextView name;

   if (v == null) {
       v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
       v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
       v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
   }

   picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
   name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

   Item item = getItem(i);

   picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
   picture.setTag(item.drawableId);
   name.setText(item.name);

   picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String imageID = v.getTag().toString();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/"+imageID);
            ((ActivityNameHere) context).showImage(uri);
        }
    });

   return v;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question is not about WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT. I want to know how to call my function showImage(final Uri imageUri)?

Comment: Error or something?

Comment: app getting crashed

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //call your showImage(final Uri imageUri) function with position/id
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but how to pass Uri from int or long variables?

Comment: Passing Uri is not a good idea. What I was trying to tell is in "K Neeraj Lal's" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `showImage` method to pass an integer resource id.

Try this,

```
public void showImage(final int imageId) {
    Dialog builder = new Dialog(this);
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //nothing;
        }
    });

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), imageId, getTheme()));
    builder.addContentView(imageView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    builder.show();
}
```

Instead of creating the dataset inside the adapter, create it in your Activity. In your `onCreate` initialize the dataset as follows.

```
private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mnt);

    mItems.add(new Item("1", R.drawable.m1));
    mItems.add(new Item("2", R.drawable.m2));
    mItems.add(new Item("3", R.drawable.m3));
    mItems.add(new Item("4", R.drawable.m4));
    mItems.add(new Item("5", R.drawable.m1));
    mItems.add(new Item("6", R.drawable.m2));

    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, mItems));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Get your image id from your Item object
            int imageId = mItems.get(position).getDrawable();
            showImage(imageId);
        }

    });
}
```

Also modify the constructor of your adapter as follows,

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> dataset) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mItems = dataset;
}
```